# When a Jehovah's Witness is reinstated how does the congregation react?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses, ecclesiology, church-discipline

When a disfellowshipped person takes the steps necessary to be accepted back into the Jehovah's Witness faith an announcement is made to the congregation informing all of the reinstatement of this person into the fold.

How is such an announcement worded and how is the congregation supposed to react to the news?

Comment: Did you know this question was in the meeting this week? I found it funny that I was doing research on this subject to answer it, and then the very next day I was studying it again as the subject of the meeting!

Comment: Ha yes I did I was going to post an answer based on the questions from readers article  I had that talk tonight.

Comment: Lol, that's awesome! Of course you're more than welcome to answer too. I didn't use that reference article in my answer.

Comment: @4castle  I think  your answer answers this question fine. Tye info on it being appropriate to have spontaneous dignified applause is actually not very on point to the way I asked this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beside baptism and marriage, reinstatement is one of the most joyous occasions Jehovah's Witnesses have. It feels very much like it did for the father of the prodigal son at [Luke 15:17-24](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/luke/15/#v42015017-v42015024), as well as for the shepherd who found his lost sheep at [Luke 15:4-7](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/luke/15/#v42015004-v42015007).

All announcements are supposed to be made in the last 3 minutes of a meeting. The reinstatement announcement is made to the congregation they were disfellowshipped from, as well as to the congregation they are currently in (if they've since moved). The announcement is basically *guaranteed* to be met with applause and is worded as:

> [Name of person] is reinstated as one of Jehovah's Witnesses.

There are some relatively new publications for ones who desire to return to the congregation. There is the brochure, [*Return to Jehovah*](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/books/return-to-jehovah/), as well as a modern-day drama, [*The Prodigal Returns*](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/videos/prodigal-son-returns/).

The brochure contains [this box](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/books/return-to-jehovah/return-to-god/#p19-p22) on the last few pages:

> **How Will The Congregation Receive Me?**
>
> You can be sure that members of
> the congregation will warmly welcome you. Rather than criticize or
> judge you, they will confirm their love for you and do whatever they
> can to encourage you.—[Hebrews 10:24, 25](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/hebrews/10/#v58010024-v58010025).
>
> *“I was embarrassed to return to the [Kingdom Hall](https://www.jw.org/en/jehovahs-witnesses/meetings/video-kingdom-hall/). I wondered how the
> friends would treat me. One of our elderly sisters who was there 30
> years ago said to me, ‘Welcome home, Son!’ That really touched my
> heart. I was truly home.”—Javier.*
>
> *“I went to the Kingdom Hall and sat
> in the last row so that no one would notice me. However, many began to
> recognize me from the days when I had attended as a child. They
> welcomed me and embraced me so affectionately that I felt an
> overwhelming peace. It was as if I had come home.”—Marco.*